# How can interact with custom payable function and metamask & etherjs?

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethers.js

I am trying to interact from the frontEnd with metamask, the etherjs library:

**"ethers": "^5.3.1",**

Based on the examples on the following website:
https://metamask.github.io/test-dapp/

But the fact is that looking at the documentation and what is in the examples, specifically, there is no example that makes use of "a function of a contract

In **my contract** have this function:

```
function storeName() external payable {
```

But all examples i have on the dapp are like this

```
const result = await ethersProvider.getSigner().sendTransaction({
      to: "0x7aE5277F207E1a288C9ad03A829AfC6035Da0B",
      value: "0x29a2241af62",
      gasLimit: 6721975,
      gasPrice: 20000000000,
    });
console.log(result);
```

https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract--methods

Looking in the documentation, I can't find a way to specify that it call method **storeName**

Comment: maybe, is good idea use another library? like as web3js?

Answer (score 1):

Please, do this:

```
    await window.ethereum.enable();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(smartContractAddress, abi, signer);
    const result = await contract.storeName({
         to: "0x7aE5277F207E1a288C9ad03A829AfC6035Da0B",
         value: "0x29a2241af62",
         gasLimit: 6721975,
         gasPrice: 20000000000,
    });
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's the same code from my example, can't see where's the place of function name storeName()

Comment: Finnally i make with web3js